# MVC 3 + REST return custom http error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

In my application I am trying to get it so that when a REST api call is made, if there is an error that it return a proper status code then either Json or Xml in the body of the response.

So `400: { 'ErrorCode': '400', 'Reason' : 'You did something wrong..' }`

or `400: <Error><ErrorCode>400</ErrorCode><Reason>You did something wrong</Reason></Error>`

However I can't seem to find how to set the status and body to make this happen. Using fiddler inspect whats being passed back and fourth I've found that if I return a normal `ActionResult` then I can return the body message ok but the status is 200. If I use `HttpException` then I can set the status code but the body message is returned as a large html document. I've tried using `HttpStatusCodeResult` but that just seems to fail and return a 302.

I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: Pretty sure thrown exceptions are passed back over Rest. Unless you have it disabled somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;` in your action method. Check out this article at develoq for a short tutorial: http://develoq.net/2011/returning-a-body-content-with-400-http-status-code/

Answer (score 2):

Web API can handle this in various ways, but if you want to stick to ASP.NET MVC then use the code below:

```
 Response.StatusCode = 500;
 Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
 return Content("Error description goes here.", "text/plain");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out MVC 4 Beta, there is a new feature called Web API that will help you solve this issue.

Comment: Can't use MVC 4 until it goes alpha I'm afraid.

Comment: @David I dont know if its the solution. But MVC 4 is is beta. http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

Comment: @Doomsknight yes apologies, I meant until it gets its official release date. Don't know why I wrote alpha :s